# Setting up motion-layouts causes path error

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I followed the gem setup instructions for [motion-layouts](https://github.com/malkomalko/motion-layouts) ...super easy.  However, the path supplied doesn't work...throws an error in the console.  The path is as follows:

```
 app.files.unshift(Dir.glob(File.join(app.project_dir, 'vendor/motion-layouts/lib/**/*.rb')))
```

The files are all in the lib directory, but they are not being loaded.  When running rake these are the errors:

```
 uninitialized constant Motion::Project (NameError)
/blah/blah/blah/vendor/motion-layouts/lib/motion-layouts.rb must be required within a  RubyMotion project Rakefile. (RuntimeError)
2013-04-20 18:58:51.675 SuperCast[81864:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RuntimeError', reason: '/blah/blah/blah/vendor/motion-layouts/lib/motion-layouts.rb must be required within a RubyMotion project Rakefile. (RuntimeError)
```

Anyone know what the problem here is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question is from a branch of the gem.  Its older.  I was suspect when I had to clone files from github.  The [gem](https://github.com/qrush/motion-layout) is the way to go.